# Setting default orientation of a view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

How can we set the default orientation of a specific view in SwiftUI and lock it in case the view only usable in landscape mode for example ?

Couldn't find anything related to swiftUI so far except from preview orientation.

Comment: Since iOS 14 brings many changes to SwiftUI regarding app lifecycle, you should probably clarify your question by adding which iOS version you want to target.

Comment: For now it's IOS 13

Answer (score 0):

Same as before, through the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key in `Info.plist`.

When you start a new project, the key should already be there containing Portrait, Landscape Left and Right by default values (everything except Portrait Upside-down). Just delete the Portrait value and leave the Landscape modes.

Comment: I want to set it as a default for a specific view, not for the entire project.